# Is there an example of r.v.'s $X,Y,Z$ where $Z \not\perp Y$ but $Z \perp Y \mid X$, i.e., where conditional independence holds, but not marginal?

Tags: probability, statistics

I am currently trying to understand how one might have 3 random variables $X,Y,Z$ where $Z$ is not marginally independent of $Y$, such that,

$$
Z \not\perp Y
$$

but is conditionally independent given $X$, such that,

$$
Z \perp Y \mid X
$$

I am assuming that $Z$ is a function of $X$, such that $Z$ depends on $X$. Is there a simple example to illustrate this?

I can think of the most trivial case where $X=Y$ and where $Z = f(X,Y)$ for some measurable function $f$ such that $Z \not\perp Y$ but $Z \perp Y \mid X$ since $X$ is a "perfect substitute" for $Y$, but it is not very illustrative. Thank you for any insights here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the most trivial/simple example I can think of: $X = Y = Z = $ any non-constant r.v., e.g. a coin-flip (with $0 < P(Heads) < 1$), $N(0,1)$, $Uniform(1000, 2019)$... whatever you want as long as it is non-constant.

Conditioned on $X,$ both $Y=Z$ are constants so they are independent.

Without conditioning, $Y=Z$ and the r.v. is non-constant so they are dependent.

---

More generally speaking, for each value of $X=x$ you can choose a different "law" for $Y,Z$ and make sure they are independent conditioned on that $x$, and then you just have to prove that when not conditioned on $X$ the "laws" mix in such a way that $Y,Z$ are dependent.  E.g. how about:

- when $X=0$ then $Y,Z$ are i.i.d. $N(0,1)$
- but when $X=1$ then $Y,Z$ are i.i.d. $Uniform(1000,2019)$?

It should be obvious that $Y \not\perp Z$.

Comment: Thanks for your great example. As a follow-up, would anything change if we knew $Y = f(X)$ for a function $f$? In other words, where Y depends on $X$?

Comment: In my first example, $X=Y=Z$, so $Y = f(X) = X$ i.e. $f()$ is the identity function.  You can also change my 2nd example to: if  $X=0$ then $Y=7, Z\sim N(0,1)$ and if $X=1$ then $Y=38, Z\sim Uniform(1000,2019)$.  Then we have $Y=f(X), Y \not\perp Z, Y\perp Z | X$.

Comment: Informally you can think of it this way: $Y \not\perp Z$ means knowing $Y$ "helps" you to guess $Z$, and $Y \perp Z | X$ means if you already know $X$, then knowing $Y$ does not help to guess $Z$ better (than if you just know $X$).  I should warn you this kind of informal thinking sometimes leads people astray!  So just use it informally, but go back to the math for proofs.

Answer (score 3):

Let $G,G'\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$ be two independent variables normally distributed and $\varepsilon\sim\mathcal B(1/2)$, that is $\mathbb P(\varepsilon=0)=\mathbb P(\varepsilon=1)=1/2$, independent of $G$ and $G'$,

Let $X=\varepsilon$, $Y=\varepsilon G$ and $Z=\varepsilon G'$.

It is clear that $Z\not\perp Y$ because they are equal on the set $\{\varepsilon=0\}$ :
$\mathbb P(Z=0,Y=0)=\mathbb P(\varepsilon=0)=1/2$

$\mathbb P(Z=0)\mathbb P(Y=0)=\mathbb P(\varepsilon =0)^2=1/4\neq1/2$.

However, given $\varepsilon$, then either $\varepsilon=0$ and $Z$ and $Y$ are seen as constant random variables so they are independent, or $\varepsilon=1$ and $Z$ and $Y$ are respectively $G$ and $G'$ which are independent. So $Z\perp Y\vert X$. If you want to check it:

$\mathbb P(Z\in A,Y\in B\vert\varepsilon=0)=\mathbb P(0\in A,0\in B\vert\varepsilon=0)=1_{A\cap B}(0)=1_A(0)1_B(0)=\mathbb P(Z\in A\vert \varepsilon=0)\mathbb P(Y\in B\vert\varepsilon=0)$

$\mathbb P(Z\in A,Y\in B\vert\varepsilon=1)=\mathbb P(G\in A,G'\in B\vert\varepsilon=1)=\mathbb P(G\in A)\mathbb P(G'\in B)=\mathbb P(G\in A\vert\varepsilon=1)\mathbb P(G'\in B\vert\varepsilon=1)=\mathbb P(Z\in A\vert\varepsilon=1)\mathbb P(Y\in B\vert\varepsilon=1)$.

Comment: Thanks for your great example. As a follow-up, would anything change if we knew $Y = f(X)$ for a function $f$? In other words, where Y depends on $X$?